# Rails activestorage not working with shopify_app gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, shopify-app

I am creating a Shopify app, I want to attach the image with the shop model.

but I can not able to start to serve when I add active storage association with the shop model.

error

> /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method` has_one_attached' for Shop (call 'Shop.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

configuration:

rails:- **6.0.1**, ruby:- **2.6.1**, shopify_app:- **11.3.2**

**This is what my code looks like now**

shop.rb

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage

  has_one_attached :icon, dependent: :destroy
end
```

config/initializers/shopify_app.rb

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|

  config.application_name = "App Name"
  config.api_key = ENV['shopify_api_key']
  config.secret = ENV['shopify_api_secret']
  config.old_secret = "<old_secret>"
  config.scope = "write_script_tags,read_script_tags,read_themes"

  config.embedded_app = false
  config.after_authenticate_job = false
  config.api_version = ShopifyVersion.shopify_api_version
  config.session_repository = Shop
  config.webhooks = [
    {topic: 'app/uninstalled', address: 'https://example.com/webhooks/app_uninstalled', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'shop/update', address: 'https://example.com/webhooks/shop_update', format: 'json'},
end
```

I tried this:
config/initializers/shopify_app.rb

```
config.session_repository = 'ShopifyApp::InMemorySessionStore'
```

but still, it's not working on the production.

error

> ShopifyApp::InMemorySessionStore::EnvironmentError (Cannot use InMemorySessionStore in a Production environment.           Please initialize ShopifyApp with a model that can store and retrieve sessions):

also, try to upgrade the gem version but no hope then create a demo with the current configuration and it will work. I can not understand why it will not work on my current project.

can anyone explain it to me?

I really appreciate your suggestions.
sorry for bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing google and try to search on the Shopify community. i got some suggestions, and base on suggestion i try to update only the shopify_app gem version and configuration base on the new version.

It works for me.

change **13.2.0** instead of **11.3.2**.